# Pods are in Pending state

Tags: kubernetes

My pods are staying in Pending state, as all the answers mentioned I tried to get describe output but no idea about why it is staying in Pending state:

```
k8s@k8s-master:~/deployment$ kubectl get nodes
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
k8s-master   Ready    master   12d   v1.12.2
k8s-node-1   Ready    <none>   12d   v1.12.2
k8s-node-2   Ready    <none>   12d   v1.12.2

k8s@k8s-master:~/deployment$ kubectl get pods           
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx       0/1     Pending   0          62m
webserver   0/1     Pending   0          13m


k8s@k8s-master:~/deployment$ kubectl describe pod webserver
Name:               webserver
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               <none>
Labels:             creator=rithin
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:                 
Containers:
  apache:
    Image:        httpd
    Port:         <none>
    Host Port:    <none>
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-vdpls (ro)
Volumes:
  default-token-vdpls:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-vdpls
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Already tried describing the pods, but no info

Comment: Can you try `kubectl get componentstatuses` and `kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o wide` ? Also, please write a about how you created this cluster and if there is anything else that's not working.

Comment: Can you try  "kubectl logs nginx"

Comment: check the `kubelet` logs with the pod name for more.

Comment: Hello here are the requested o/ps:

`Last login: Sat Mar 23 04:20:50 2019 from 106.51.21.252
k8s@k8s-master:~$ kubectl logs nginx
k8s@k8s-master:~$ kubectl get componentstatuses
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE              ERROR
scheduler            Healthy   ok                   
controller-manager   Healthy   ok                   
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health": "true"}`

Comment: `kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o wide` all pods in kube-system namespace is running, only the ones in default namespace is pending

Comment: I installed the k8s using kudeadm and using flannel for n/wg

Comment: Can you post full output of `kubect describe pod nginx ` commad

Comment: @RithinSkaria Please also share the output of `kubectl get pod webserver -o yaml`

Answer (score 1):

Your pods require manual scheduling. 
In your yaml file for the pods add 
`nodeName: k8s-master`
at the same level of containers under spec.

Your pods would be scheduled at the k8s-master node. If you want to schedule it in any other node, replace "k8s-master" with the appripriate node name.

Answer (score 0):

One possiblity is that worker node is not reachable from master node as there is no node assigned to the pod.

Answer (score 0):

Well I couldn't find any logs related to failure. So recreated the cluster and now it is working. I assume it was a problem with flannel.